# WSO2-Call an API to got file from SFTP

Tags: wso2-esb

The story is that there is a SFTP server for .csv file, and client wants to call an API to get the .csv data in json format. How do I implement this business scenario with a wso2 esb(4.8.1)? Thanks a lot for any idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an ESB API,

1. Use [file connector](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Working+with+the+File+Connector) to search and read the file
2. Use [smooks mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Smooks+Mediator) to convert the content in to XML
3. Use [messageType](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Generic+Properties#GenericProperties-messageType) and [ContentType](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Generic+Properties#GenericProperties-ContentType) properties to convert the XML payload to JSON

Comment: Thanks a lot for your idea first, but [file connector download](https://store.wso2.com/store/assets/esbconnector/details/5d6de1a4-1fa7-434e-863f-95c8533d3df2) describe that it is not support ESB 4.8.1. I have tried to use [VFS Transport](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/VFS+Transport) to get the file and insert data into database for api, but there is another problem about [DB Report Mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/DB+Report+Mediator), it seems that DB Report Mediator is not support Transaction control,right?I am not sure about this

Comment: Yeah DB Report mediator do not support transaction control. You can use WSO2 DSS with boxcarring. http://harshcreationz.blogspot.com/2015/02/boxcarring-sample-with-wso2-dss-and.html